# php7.0-mcrypt can't install on ubuntu14.04

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, php-7.0

phpmyadmin show error **[ The mcrypt extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.]** on nginx. My PHP version is *PHP 7.0.33-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)*.
When I install **php7.0-mcrypt**, package doesn't exist.How to install php7.0-mcrypt?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your message, you're using ubuntu 14.04. I recommend you upgrade your system. You could find this package in some latest [reseases](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php7.0-mcrypt).

Or you could install this package manually `wget http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/php7.0/php7.0-mcrypt_7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i php7.0-mcrypt_7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4_amd64.deb`. But be careful, you could face some dependency hell and damage your OS.